Multi-Condition Check in Batch
Is there a way to check for multiple conditions at once, then perform a given action if all conditions are met at once? I will use a file check as example:

I know fileA exists, but I am unsure if fileB does. Assuming it does, the logic would be something along the lines of:

if exist "fileA" & if exist "fileB" goto :success

If fileB doesn't exist, I will fallthrough to an error and loop back until the condition is met.

The issue I am having is that through numerous tests I cannot find a way to do this the way I need. I can check for fileA, then fileB in a separate function later in the code but I need to check for both at once and execute my next command if both of the conditions are true or false depending. Ideally this  would also work for three, or four, or potentially more conditions I need to check for so I would need it to scale if the number of conditions I check for changes.

Remove the &. if exist "fileA" if exist "fileB" goto :success. Which cases do you need to distinguish? Only two cases for all files exists or else? Or different cases for combinations like both files exist or A exists, B does not or A does not exist, B does or no file exists?

CMD's IF is very basic and only allows for one comparison at a time. There is support for else and also not, and you can string multiple if's in a row by using the goto.
Powershell's if has support for multiple checks, so it would be easier to just use powershell.
That said, here's how to do it in batch, taking your FileA and FileB instead of paths to actual files:
    @echo off

    IF NOT EXIST fileA GOTO Fail

::  -- we reached this point, so fileA exists.

    IF NOT EXIST fileB GOTO Fail

::  -- we reached this point, so fileB also exists.

    GOTO Success

:Fail
    Echo Aw... One or both of the files did not exist.
    GOTO END

:Success
    echo Yay, both files exists.
    GOTO END

:end


I was just going to say that, using two IF statements, is essentially the same as checking two conditionals in a single IF statement. I would just use PowerShell and avoid the limitations of batch though.

@Ramhound note that I checked using the NOT operator. Also, OP mentioned that they want to be able to expand the list of files to check, and using this approach, not only can you extend the list indefinitely without getting one huge line of nested ifs that will become hard to read pretty quick, you can also put other checks in the same path and manage that easily. I made the script so that it is both very easy to read and easy to maintain.

I use GOTO statements all the time so i have no problem with this approach

A simplistic option for few files where they are listed on the same line with dir /w "file1" "file2" | findstr /i "file1.*file2", however with the quantity limited and subject to the length of characters in the file name.
@echo off

>nul dir /w "FileA.log" "FileB.log" "FileC.log" | findstr /i "FileA.log.*FileB.log.*FileB.log" && =;(
   goto :success );= || echo/nOp!&& goto :fail

:success
echo/ Your three files exist! 
goto :end

:fail
echo/one or more files not found
goto :end

:end


An option to count the number of files found and/or not found using an if integer equal integer to direct the true/false processing flow, not limited to the number of files nor the character length of the name, would be:
@echo off && Setlocal

set /a "_Count=0, _Missing=0"
cd /d "D:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\Folder"

set "_files="FileA.log","FileB.log","FileC.log","FileD.log","FileE.log","FileF.log","FileG.log","FileH.log","FileI.log","FileJ.log","FileL.log","FileM.log""

:: or .. 
::
:: set "_files="FileA.log","FileB.log","FileC.log","FileD.log""
:: set "_files=%_files%,"FileE.log","FileF.log","FileG.log","FileH.log""
:: set "_files=%_files%,"FileI.log","FileJ.log","FileL.log","FileM.log""

for /f %%G in =;(' 2^>nul where %_files%
    ');= do call set /a "_Count+=1"

if 1%_Count% EQU 112 =;( goto %:^O) else goto %:^(

%:^O
set "_founded=00000%_Count%"
timeout -1 | echo/%_Coun:~-3% files exist!
goto %:^/

%:^(
set /a "_fail=12-%_Count%"
set "_missing=0000%_fail%"
set "_founded=00000%_Count%" 

timeout -1 | ;=( 
     echo/%_founded:~-3% files exist!.. 
     echo/%_missing:~-3% files not exist!..
    );=
    
%:^/
endlocal & goto :eOf



Output in false condition for 1 file not existing/found:

011 files exist!..
001 files not exist!..



Some further reading:

CD /?

If /?

Set /?

For /?

For /F /?

Find /?

Where /?

Findstr /?

Setlocal | Endlocal /?

Using: Conditional Execution

|| and &&


Where does GOTO :EOF return to?

Using: Commands with Redirection

|, <, >, 2>, 2>&1, etc.


Using: Goto :Label
| and /or | Using: Call :Label

Using: Set _Varibel=%_Varibel:~X,-Y%

An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com


